# Merge rows of data into one table without removing the ID tags

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have about 279,900 rows of data which look like the following

```
Product       Attribute1    Attribute options 2
BOSTON-6543    Black         Plain
BOSTON-6543     Cordovan    Plain
BOSTON-6543     Red         Plain
BOSTON-6543    Black       Basketweave
BOSTON-6543     Black      Ballistic Weave Nylon
BOSTON-6543     Black      Plain
BOSTON-6543     Black      Plain
BOSTON-6543     Black      Plain
BOSTON-6543     Black      Plain
BOSTON-6543     Black      Plain
BOSTON-6543 Black   Plain
BOSTON-6543 Black   Plain
BOSTON-6543 Black   Plain
BOSTON-6543 Red Plain
BOSTON-6543 Black   Basketweave
BOSTON-6543 Black   Ballistic Weave Nylon
```

and I would like to merge it to look like this

```
Product Attribute1                        Attribute options 2   
BOSTON-6543 Black||cordovan||red    Plain||Basketweake||Ballistic weave     nylon   
BOSTON-6543 Black||cordovan||red    Plain||Basketweake||Ballistic weave nylon   
BOSTON-6543 Black||cordovan||red    Plain||Basketweake||Ballistic weave nylon   
BOSTON-6543 Black||cordovan||red    Plain||Basketweake||Ballistic weave nylon   
BOSTON-6543 Black||cordovan||red    Plain||Basketweake||Ballistic weave nylon   
BOSTON-6543 Black||cordovan||red    Plain||Basketweake||Ballistic weave nylon   
BOSTON-6543 Black||cordovan||red    Plain||Basketweake||Ballistic weave nylon   
BOSTON-6543 Black||cordovan||red    Plain||Basketweake||Ballistic weave nylon   
BOSTON-6543 Black||cordovan||red    Plain||Basketweake||Ballistic weave nylon   
BOSTON-6543 Black||cordovan||red    Plain||Basketweake||Ballistic weave nylon   
BOSTON-6543 Black||cordovan||red    Plain||Basketweake||Ballistic weave nylon   
BOSTON-6543 Black||cordovan||red    Plain||Basketweake||Ballistic weave nylon   
BOSTON-6543 Black||cordovan||red    Plain||Basketweake||Ballistic weave nylon   
BOSTON-6543 Black||cordovan||red    Plain||Basketweake||Ballistic weave nylon   
BOSTON-6543 Black||cordovan||red    Plain||Basketweake||Ballistic weave nylon   
BOSTON-6543 Black||cordovan||red    Plain||Basketweake||Ballistic weave nylon
```

These are in Excel spreadsheets with the labels product attribute and attribute options 2.

I need to keep each row of the product name, I need to merge each attribute row to that specific ID so that I can cut and paste the entire 270K row lines into another spreadsheet for a import.

Comment: Please edit your code for better readability.

Comment: With four spaces ('    ') you can make your text to a column. Use spaces to indent. Always add source data to your question. I think you left out info on how the link between BOSTON-6543 Black and cordovan can be established for example.

Comment: Please explain what are the rules\criteria used to perform the concatenation. 
Notice that all output lines in you sample are identical. 
It seems that you are just concatenating all possible attributes for each product. 
Do you really need the 270K records (including all the records repeated many times) or just one record per product will do, if so suggest to use a pivot table to obtain al combinations at once then concatenate the results to obtain one record per product

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `concatenate` and `vlookup`. Concatenate for adding the space and pipes, and vlookup to look up the unique identifier in some table, to get the result.

Based on the given info there's not enough info to give an very precise answer, but I think my answer will get you on track.

In a cell put this formula to get something as desired. Adjust to your own need.

```
=Workbook1!A2&" || "&VLOOKUP(A2;Workbook1!A1:C3;3;UNTRUE)
```

The statement does the following:

```
Workbook1!A2                           fetch the value in cell A2 of workbook1
&" || "                                concatenate space pipe pipe space
&VLOOKUP(A2;Workbook1!A1:C3;3;UNTRUE)  find the value A2 in column A, and give back the 
                                       third column of the row that has the same value 
                                       as A2.
                                       With UNTRUE you say to give the exact corresponding 
                                       value. With TRUE you an give an approximate when 
                                       the A2 is something near the value of A2. For 
                                       example if you had vlookupped 30 and the two most 
                                       near values were 20 and 40. But that's another 
                                       question... Hope this helps.
```

*consider a 'vote up' or 'answered by' if this helps you out.

Comment: for some reason when I cut and pasted it did not show right.

Comment: I have 3 rows. 1 is row a "product" 2 is "attribute1" 3 is "Attribute option 1"

Comment: for the product row. If I have 20/30/100 different options of a product each product it will list needs it own line.

Comment: these are for the drop down box options so it knows that this option for the drop down has those attributes. I already how the SKU and attributes finished but it has been these rows of data that has been giving me the trouble as they all have to be the same and they all have to keep there lines instead of merging all 10/20/30 lines into 1 line like it has been doing.

Comment: I am not a excel person so I hope I explained that right

Comment: =Workbook1!A2&" || "&VLOOKUP(A2;Workbook1!A1:C3;3;UNTRUE)

Comment: Did you replace Workbook1! with the name of the workbook where your table stands? Try to write the code yourself. Go to a cell, type '=' (without the ' '), then look what excel says, select the column, type in &" " etc. I do remember some languages have other use of ';' (as ',') and ' " ' as ' ' '. Other idea... Put your excel somehwere so I can look at it.

Comment: I also only need to merge the values of Black||cordovan||red which is row B. row A needs to be seperate from row b and c and only row b and c need to be merged for those ids in row a

Comment: how can I upload a copy of this excel sheet

Comment: Also I did replace the book1 with the sheet 1 which highlights the rows I want to work with but gives me a error